# Web service for Accessing Google GSA Search Logs

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am using GSA 7.2, I have one module for search log analysis, For that module I need to export logs data from GSA and import into the module. This import and export I need to do manually, For this logs I want to know is there any Web Service/Feeds from GSA to get logs data.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some log data via the admin API using the gdata client but you won't be able to get ASR data etc, for that you'll need to write an HTTP client of your own or stick to exporting manually.

[7.2 Admin API doco](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/acapi_protocol/acapi_protocol.html)

[gdata client site](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDoQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fgoogle-enterprise-gdata-api%2F&ei=o5dtVZfVOYL-7Abt34LICg&usg=AFQjCNHsb9tWe1srvFLzVSRaPyTiW1jE7Q&bvm=bv.94455598,d.ZGU)